# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') in flutterwave-node-v3 library

Tags: node.js, express, axios, payment-gateway, flutterwave

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm facing an issue while using the flutterwave-node-v3 library in my Node.js project. I'm trying to create an order using the flw.orders.create method, but I keep getting the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') at checkout (C:\Users\kv4biz\Desktop\mojoyOnline\Ecommerce(backend)\controller\paymentCtrl.js:16:34)`

Here's the relevant part of my `paymentCtrl.js` file:

```
const Flutterwave = require("flutterwave-node-v3");
require("dotenv").config();
const flw = new Flutterwave(
  process.env.FLW_PUBLIC_KEY,
  process.env.FLW_SECRET_KEY
);

const checkout = async (req, res) => {
  const { amount } = req.body;
  const option = {
  amount: amount * 100,
  currency: "NGN",
  redirect_url: "YOUR_REDIRECT_URL",
  payment_options: "card,mobilemoney,ussd",
};
const order = await flw.orders.create(option); // This line causes the error
  res.json({
   success: true,
   order,
  });
};

// ... other functions ...

module.exports = {
 checkout,
 paymentVerification,
```

};

I have confirmed that the `flutterwave-node-v3` package is installed, and I have set the correct `FLW_PUBLIC_KEY` and `FLW_SECRET_KEY` in my environment variables.

Can anyone please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to fix it? I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue.

Thank you!